# html and css slider not loading on page refresh but works well when click on nxt or pre button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the html code and JavaScript code, on page refresh slider images does not get loaded but after clicking the next button of slider it works well but after page refresh images disappear.

```
<div class="slide-banner">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="assets/3387c282bae062cc6efada9402ef42ad.jpg" />

        </div>
        <div class="slide">
                <img src="assets/iPhone-Text-Monitoring-on-Apple-Devices-Yes-And-So-Much-More.jpg" />

        </div>
        <div class="slide">
                <img src="assets/pexels-photo-168765.jpeg" />

        </div>
        <div class="slide">
                <img src="assets/pexels-photo-355988.jpeg" />

        </div>
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
```

Comment: It's not complete code provide complete javascript and html code.

Comment: here is javascript code

Comment: var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}

Comment: Please edit your question and not put code in comments

Comment: please review will it working. https://jsfiddle.net/dipakchavda2912/o5e4gkg2/9/

Comment: I think your are missing out  window.onload

Comment: no it is not working

Comment: Amal here lucky did not show his code only in body so I did not use window.onload

Comment: lucky review blow answer and let me know.

Comment: not working already tried

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please review my snippet it may help to resolve your issue.
You should use absolute path rather than the relative path in image src. And called plusSlides(1) method rather than showSlides().

```js
var slideIndex = 1;

plusSlides(1);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   plusSlides(1);
});
```

```html
<div class="slide-banner">
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />

  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />

  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x700/000/fff" />

  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x200/000/fff" />

  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
```

Comment: @lucky can you tell what happens with snippet. what is an issue with code?

Comment: i tried it but not working for me still facing issues

Comment: on refresh screen goes blank and after clicking the next or prev button slider gets loaded

Comment: @luckyyadav I shall give you proper solution.

Comment: @luckyyadav atleast let me know before give downvote

Comment: without your full code, I am not able to give you an answer.